# Postgresql - [Novice alert] Using case and count in SQL query

Tags: postgresql, count, case

I have a table which has the following columns:

Table name: students

```
ID | Result
1  | 0
4  | 1
2  | 0
3  | 1
4  | 1
1  | 1
```

The Result can be either 0 or 1 which indicates "failed" or "passed" respectively. The table can have multiple entries of the same ID (same student).

My goal is to create a view called "status" which looks like this:

View name: status

```
ID  |  Final_Result
1   |  Failed
2   |  Failed
3   |  Passed
4   |  Passed
```

Which is, if a student has failed even in one subject, his Final_Result should be "Failed". Otherwise it will be a "Passed".

I'm a complete novice at Postgresql and getting my feet wet. I tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE View status AS
SELECT  ID,
        Result,
          CASE 
          WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
          ELSE 'Passed'
          END AS Final_Result
FROM students
GROUP BY ID;
```

But that is obviously not right. I suppose I need to use the COUNT function to count the number of 0s and then perform the CASE statement but I'm not familiar with that in SQL.

Can someone please help me and put me on the right track? Thank you.

Comment: something like `case min(Result) when 0 then 'Failed' else 'Passed' end as Final_Result`. The group by looks fine

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **COUNT**, use agregate function **bool_and**(**Result=1**)

```
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN bool_and(Result=1) THEN 'Passed' ELSE 'Failed' END AS Final_Result  

FROM students
GROUP BY id
```

Your example with COUNT and SUM

```
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN COUNT()=SUM(Result) THEN 'Passed' ELSE 'Failed' END AS Final_Result  

FROM students
GROUP BY id
```